# Download gwtp-carstore steps

Tags: maven, gwt, gwtp

I would like to try a copy of gwtp-carstore.

Step 1: Download https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP via GitHub app

Step 2: In eclipse select import Maven Projects then browse to gwtp-carstore
I then get the error

No marketplace entries found to handle maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6:unpack in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.

I select resolve later - then I get the error

Could not get configured mojo for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.7:checkstyle {execution: validate}
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.gwtplatform:gwtp-build-tools:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.apache.org/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced

From the command line I've run

mvn generate-sources and I get the errors
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.7:checkstyle (validate) on project gwtp-carstore: Execution validate of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.7:checkstyle failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.gwtplatform:gwtp-build-tools:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Took a github checkout

Step 2 - Import into eclipse as maven project (it just downloaded half the internet i guess!!)

Step 3 - Use "Quick Fix" option from the "Marker" view to solve two maven errors as you report.

[image]

Step 4 - Fix error for "Update project configuration" account of above POM changes.

**Remove/Disable the checkstyle plugin if the above steps do not help.**

Comment: Thank you for your advice,  Did this work for you?  I managed to get passed the checkstyle plugin problem but cannot get this sample to run

Comment: I only set up the project for code reference. Had never run it. Maybe i will give this a go once and update.